# Interesting PHP syntax: an 'implied if'?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I came across this interesting line in the default index.php file for a Zend Framework project:

```
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

It seems to be saying "If APPLICATION_PATH is not defined, then go on and define it..."

I'm not aware of this control structure in PHP.  It's almost like an 'implied if' or 'if/else'.  Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not a control structure - it is just how `||` works. If first operand was evaluated to `true` - then second is not being evaluated at all.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php --- look at the first 4 lines of the sample.

```
// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Comment: Conversely, only if the first expression is false, the second is evaluated.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams: obviously - yes ;-)

Comment: +1 good! Further reading at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: I get that you get it, but not everybody knows that the PHP or operator is short circuited.  The take-away here is that when you have to pick what to evaluate first in your or operators, pick the one that's most likely to be true, and failing that, the one that's faster to evaluate.  The second one may never get checked if you pick wisely.

Answer (score 4):

`||` is a short-circuiting operator. If the left-hand operand is `true`, the expression as a whole *must* be `true`, so it won't bother evaluating the right-hand operand. You can use `&&` in a reverse manner; if the left-hand operand is `false`, the expression as a whole must be `false`, so the right-hand operand won't be evaluated.

This is a rather idiomatic way to do things in some other languages. I'd usually prefer an explicit `if` in PHP though for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is just some boolean expression that gets evaluated but throws away the result. It's using short-circuit logic to assure that the latter half of it is only run when the first half is false.

Similarly, you can capture the result:

```
$foo = false || true;  // $foo will contain true.
```

Comment: And there's always the lovely ternary operator:  `$action = ( defined('APPLICATION_PATH') ) ? 'default' : define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application')); `

Comment: @editor why to use ternary if logical is working fine and more readable

Answer (score 2):

This is a [short-circuiting evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) of a boolean expression, which is indeed a way to accomplish something like an if-else.